Film scans came back bright blue
I just bought a new canon sure shot telemax and the first roll I developed came back all bright blue images. I am wondering, is this likely to be an issue with the film that was in it (the camera came with a roll in it, so I used this role) or an issue with the camera?

It would probably help if you could paste in one of the scanned frames (suitably reduced in size).   That would help distinguish between a scanning error and a developing error, for instance.

Yeah, fair...I tried to do that when I made the post, I can't figure out how to upload one. It seems the image has to be a link and I don't know how to do that, all I have is the downloaded scans I could upload here.

Start with uploading the image to pastebin and that will get you a link you can paste into the post, then someone who knows this stuff better than me can help get the image embedded.

That sounds like it might be the negative of the orange film base on color negs.  It may go away if you use auto-levels or another white balance technique.

Sounds to me like it's a scanning error. I don't think the camera or the film itself would cause this issue. Scanning the film without compensating for the orange mask would create an overall blue cast.
You don't say who or how it was processed. It's hard to believe that a professional processor would make such a mistake, but I think that's the most likely cause. If you processed it yourself and are scanning the negs yourself then see what daveolfman has to say above...

It could also be an artifact of (accidental) cross-processing...

Thank you everyone. I got the scans from a professional place so I am not sure but I am going to reach out and ask them. Much appreciated!
